# How to successfully connect to a localhost blockchain node?

Tags: web3js

I have a localhost blockchain node successfully working and my contract deploys OK using truffle. Geth works too. But when I try and access the node via **React** and the Chrome console when running React I am not getting anything meaningful. Even web3.eth.coinbase does not work.

Example code -

```
 var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));


var x = web3.eth.coinbase;
```

And x is undefined.

Here is the connection string -

> geth --datadir ~/blockchain/mybc1 --rpc --rpcaddr "localhost" --port
>   8545 --rpcport 8545 --networkid 1234 console 2> consolemybc1.log

Has anyone any ideas about this?

Comment: The '--port' specifies the p2p port, which, by default is 30303. It shouldn't be the same as the "--rpcport" . Try removing the "--port 8545" and see what happens?

Comment: I changed that and the same issue exists.

Comment: Try adding --rpccorsdomain '*' (notice the single quote) ?

Comment: Done - same issues. I think web3 was changed too? But is there a way to debug the connection?

Comment: Check for web3 itself... is it still undefined... if it is not...you can check web3.version.api

Comment: web3
n {_requestManager: s, currentProvider: i, eth: n, db: e.exports, shh: a, …}
web3.version.api
"0.20.3"

Comment: web3.isConnected()
false

Comment: Use: geth --datadir ~/blockchain/mybc1 --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcport 8545 --networkid 1234 console 2> consolemybc1.log

Comment: I finally found out the error. Somehow the installation had different versions. The default for web3 is 1.0 beta which does not work. I had 0.20.2 showing but somehow the default was running due to the require('web3'). I am testing now.

Answer (score 1):

The installation somehow had different versions. The default is 1.0 using npm install web3 which fails.

Here is the correct installation -

```
npm install web3@0.20.2
```

Reference -
https://www.versioneye.com/nodejs/web3/0.20.2